# Using Outlook 2010, is there a way to change the default reply to behavior to set a default mail independent of the address it was sent to?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Using Outlook 2010, is there a way to change the default reply to behavior to set a default mail independent of the address it was sent to?

I receive emails from several webforms, on various sites. I want to ensure that the mail is replied to from my work address, not the info@ style address that the form uses.

I would prefer to avoid unsigned Macros, as Outlook seems to have security issues with actually running them, even if permissions have been given. If that is something I can change,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that solely from within Outlook, but there is one guy out there, who specializes in Outlook/Microsoft Exchange (e-mail server) software.

If you are using just Outlook, you can buy this software:

http://www.ivasoft.com/setfrom.shtml

If you are using Microsoft Exchange as your server, you can buy the product below, which will allow you to do it for all users in your Exchange environment.

http://www.ivasoft.com/choosefrom2007.shtml (for Exchange 2007/2010)

http://www.ivasoft.biz/choosefrom.shtml (for Exchange 2003)

Comment: I appreciate the option, and it does do what I asked for. I'm looking for a way to do it for myself, however. If that requires programming a plug in or macro, so be it, but that would be a last resort. You are very positive that it is not possible another way? I really don't mean to push my luck, but may I ask where you found the information? :)

Comment: Can I say that something does not exist? Who knows, how can you prove a negative? But my info comes mostly from 17 years of IT experience, where I seem to do a ton of e-mail. For example, I used to manage (with many people below me) 52,000 e-mail users for a Fortune 50 company (and several more large installs, although not quite as large), and just last week, I deployed Exchange for a company in the US and Europe remotely. I just seem to do a lot of e-mail. I am certain you cannot do it natively. If you think you can program it, feel free, but I would just spend the $50 and save the time.

Comment: @zenbike If nothing else, if you are worried about an outside software and security, but it is not about the $50, you could still buy it, and reverse engineer it...it might give you some ideas.

Comment: I understand, and I was not trying to be combatative. I wanted to understand the experience behind the answer. As you have a lot of experience, I will put a lot more weight behind your words. Thank you for your time. BTW, if there's a better way to find out whether the person answering a question is trustworthy, or a better way to ask the question, please let me know. I'm new to all this. :-)

Comment: That's not a bad idea. It would give me a place to start at least. Thanks.

Comment: @zenbike I did not take it as combative, and I did not mind explaining why. The levels of skill here vary greatly, but I have enjoyed (OK been a bit addicted) to answering questions lately. Since I work for myself, I can waste my time as I please in case you wonder why I would be here in the first place.

Comment: I appreciate your "wasting" your time with my issues. See you around, I'm sure.

Comment: @zenbike Sorry, I certainly did not mean it like that, or any offense...I just meant some people could look at it that way.

Comment: No offense was taken. I was sincerely thanking you for your time. No worries. I have a bit of a dry sense of humor. It goes over well on the interwebs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I published a free Outlook add-on to accomplish it without Exchange. It is all explained on [Removing the “On Behalf Of” Message from Outlook](http://blog.nektra.com/main/2012/06/06/removing-the-on-behalf-of-message-from-outlook/)

Answer (score 0):

good suggestion here:  http://www.outlook-tips.net/configuration/always-reply-using-a-different-account/

No added software.  Works for me.

Comment: Replicate the answer with attribution. A link is better off as a comment, because links tend to break.